# How to return parents in path, and locate key in JSON

Tags: python, json, key

I'm trying to figure out how to find a key called ['text'] and then get the parent keys from the nest. It's the third key that's different, all the other tags are the same.

```
    html_data = data['data']['document_data']['dataItem-ihmty5rw']['text']
```

I'm using this function to get the keys:

```
    def printKeysValues(d):
      for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            printKeysValues(v)
        else:
          print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))
```

And this function to find the indent:

```
   def pretty(d, indent=0):
     for key, value in d.items():
        print('\t' * indent + str(key))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            pretty(value, indent+1)
        else:
            print('\t' * (indent+1) + str(value))
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want your final output to be?

Comment: The final output is the value of ['text'] key for similar files. The main problem is that they're deeply nested, and difficult to find.

Comment: Are you saying you just want a print-out of all values under the "text" key in a nested dictionary? And if so, is the "text" key always the 4th nested key?

Comment: In this case yes, the value of the text key, and it's the 4th nested key. I want to work with the other keys as well, but they're also at the 4th level, below the variable key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure if this is what you wanted, but if you just want the text per item dictionary, I think this should work:

```
# a dictionary of item string to dictionary containing a "text" key
item_map = data['data']['document_data']  

for item_string, item_map in item_map.iteritems():
    print item_string  # the item string (e.g. 'dataItem-ihmty5rw')
    print item_map['text']  # this is the text associated with the item string
```

Comment: Thanks Karin, it works. I added a line before the print statements `if item_map.get('text'):` to filter out the other tags at the third level.